# Reference for "holomorphic contact geometry"

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic

Just like holomorphic symplectic geometry is a complexification of real symplectic geometry, I am wondering is there any good survey paper or book talking about holomorphic version of real contact geometry?

Comment: Maybe the references in the following would help: Stefan Kebekus, Thomas Peternell, Andrew J. Sommese, and Jarosław A. Wiśniewski. Projective contact manifolds. Invent. Math., 142(1):1–15, 2000.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger, thank you very much!